# covariant derivative orthogonal projection formular

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, covariance

Good evening,

i try to understand following proof from Carmo: Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces

[image]

I have two Questions:

1. Why is $ e_1 \times e_2=N$ and $N \times e_1 =e_2$
   Is it because $e_1, e_2$ are the unit vectors tangent to the coordinate curve and and so with $N$ a moving trihedron? And is it important for that, that $F=0$
2. Why is this equation true?

$$ \left \langle \left ( \frac{x_u}{\sqrt{E}}\right )_u,\frac{x_v}{\sqrt{G}} \right \rangle = - \frac{1}{2}\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}$$

how can I generate it from

$$\langle x_{uu},x_{v} \rangle=-\frac{1}{2}E_v $$

Thanks

EDIT: Solved the first question with [Geodesic curvature for orthogonal parametrization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913953/geodesic-curvature-for-orthogonal-parametrization)

Comment: P.S. Now that I have your attention, you never responded to our queries about [your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580348/formular-for-gauß-curvature). Where did that (erroneous?) formula come from?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748974/gaussian-curvature-k-of-of-orthogonal-parametrization-x   is a Question in Carmo: Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces. And you get it from the Gauß-Formular and Theorema egregium

Comment: This formula holds only for $F=0$, as I already discussed in the previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $F=0$ is essential in all this. $e_1,e_2,N$ form an (oriented) orthonormal basis.

For your second question, just use the product rule and the fact that $\langle x_u,x_v\rangle = 0$. It falls out immediately.

Comment: Thanks for helping me